# Error clipping raster by extent QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

While trying to clip raster using X,Y values this kind of error occurs:

> GDAL command output:
> ERROR 3: Free disk space available is 73209118720 bytes, whereas 1781328410624 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.
> Input file size is 7831, 7921
> Process returned error code 1

I can add that EPSG code is the same as the one used in the project.

Comment: I suppose that the pixel size of the output image is defined all too small for some reason.